# Lost my admin menu in Debian/GNOME

Tags: debian, gnome

I lost my admin menu in Debian during an update. For example I need to disable automatic time-update, and then change the time, but can't find it in my menus.

I am running the GUI as a regular user, and when it worked I would have to enter an admin password to make changes.

1. How do I get it back in my menus?
2. Is there some command-line interface to launch?

Comment: sounds like a sudoers issue but I am not sure about the default setup of debian and sudo https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#The_Default_Ubuntu_Sudoers_File  maybe ubuntu helps

Comment: It was lost during upgrades, so it should not be the issue (but thanks)

Comment: Any luck? I'm stuck with this issue too :(

Comment: Could you check if you're using Gnome 3? This new version don't have the admin menu by default. The fix for Ubuntu should also apply on Debian.

Comment: I don't work on that computer anymore, so i can't verify.  But the answer looks quite good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One [source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102485) advices to reinstall the gnome-system-tools package to restore the menu.

Another [source](http://forums.opensuse.org/archives/sf-archives/archives-software/338324-gnome-menu-missing.html) advices to reinstall the gnome-main-menu and gnome-main-menu-devel (not required) packages, and adding the nautilus-gnome-main-menu package.

Still another [source](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=173406) advices :

> I find ~/.gconf and ~/.gconfd and move them to gconf and gconfd. I
>   copy /root/.gconf and /root/.gconfd to ~, change the owner, relog. I
>   do see the top panel!

The thread 
[Ubuntu 11.10 Upgrade: Missing Your System Menu (Preferences & Administration) Launchers?](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/ubuntu-11-10-upgrade-missing-your-system-menu-preferences-administration-launchers/),
although for Ubuntu rather than Debian, makes interesting reading.
You might try the several solutions mentioned in it.

Other people admit giving up on this and going with KDE or Unity.